# Why Math Type WIRISplugins.js does not parse the mathml rendered in react component?

Tags: reactjs, plugins, mathtype, wiris

I am trying to render some formulas stored in the DB in mathml, in the react app i am using the  plugin as suggested here: [wiris](https://docs.wiris.com/mathtype/en/mathtype-integrations/mathtype-web-interface-features/full-mathml-mode---wirisplugins-js.html?).
by adding to the head the tag: `<script src="https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/app/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image"></script>`
however, the svg images are not generated and just the mathml is showing.

After this, I tried adding it using a useEffect:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/app/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image';
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    }, []);
```

And also did not work at first, but when i change the `document.head.appendChild(script);` line to `document.body.appendChild(script);` the HMR fires and that moment the `WIRISplugins.js` works and convert the mathml into images. but if i do a manual reload it again stop working.